# Possible alternative to combo of Lua and C++; that has 3rd party libraries

Tags: python, c++, lua, executable

I code frequently in python. It does help me in rapid prototyping, debugging capability and the vast amount of 3rd party libraries. Recently, I'm wary of the huge size (min 10Mb), slow startup times and focusing a bit on performance, startup time and executable size of scripts/applications.

Recently, I came across c++ with lua. where you can build the core with c++ and the script in lua for everything else dynamic. C++ helps in areas of performance and lua takes care of rapid script developement and debug. The C++ executable and lua.dll is small enough that whole bundle takes ~500kB. Lua installation size is small (880kB). I don't have to install much to get started (unlike rust - which required Visual studio of ~10GB).  The only problem is that it doesn't provide the 3rd party libraries (the way python does).
I did try lua with python, but seems there's not much improvement in performance.

Is there any other alternative from general purpose programming languages that can satisfy the below criterias? ( apart from Java, Javascript )

```
1. 3rd party library
2. Rapid prototyping and debug
3. performance
4. small installation size and small executable size
```

Answer (score 1):

try Go: large number of third-party libraries | fast compilation and startup times | statically typed language | has built-in support for embedding other programming languages like Lua or Python(you can uyilize the performance and control of Go for the core of your application and then use a scripting language for dynamic functionality)

while this doesn't provide the exact combination of C++ and Lua, you can leverage the features to get similar benefits

Comment: Executables aren't exactly small though